# How to use pdb effectively to debug Django?

Tags: python, django, debugging, pdb

I have been recommended to use pdb to understand and debug Django applications. Though I haven't found it very effective and want to learn how to avail maximum gain. To debug, below is how I generally proceed:

I set breakpoint at most suspicious code section or at a point where control is going and then proceed with next or continue. As method completes I found myself in Django source code with no hint how to proceed to next code section written by developer. Previously I have worked on big C++ application and gdb was really helpful to understand control flow and debug. I want to achieve same thing with pdb for Django project at hand and any help even apart from pdb is appreciated?

Comment: I somehow have gone through your experience. One useful move is the the `s` command (step into) in order to enter functions that are called within your code. Another useful comand is `b`, to set breakpoints, so that you ensure your code stops every time it goes through it. Anyway, pdb has many options, and nothing more useful that reading the documentation with love (it has no secrets). In addition, I would recommend using `pudb` instead (it has some more cool features: https://asmeurersympy.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/pudb-a-better-python-debugger/)

Comment: I usually work with runserver_plus which is part of [django extension](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). But this only helps when an exception is raised. For development I use `ipdb`. [It's easy to use](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/11/18/intro-python-debugger/)